# Object is possibly 'undefined' Nuxt 3, vee-validate 4.7

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, vee-validate, nuxt3

```
import {
  Field,
  Form as CustomForm,
  useForm,
  defineRule,
  configure,
} from 'vee-validate'
import { required, email, min, numeric } from '@vee-validate/rules'
defineRule('required', required)
defineRule('email', email)
defineRule('min', min)
defineRule('numeric', numeric)

configure({
  generateMessage: ({ rule }) => {
    return this.$t('validate.' + rule?.name)
  },
})

export { Field, CustomForm, useForm }
```

This.$t (Object is possibly 'undefined')
I want to use other languages when checking validation

I tried to create a new file where all the translations are defined, but there is still an error, maybe someone has encountered something like this or knows how to solve it?
I don't know how to make it display my translation, since the translation from vee-validate/i18n is poor I would like to use my own

Comment: Where this object is defined ? Actually it's never done in the given code

Comment: in general, if I have a login.vue component then during the popup I use this.$t('login.success') and everything works, so I thought the translation in this file would work similarly